# Intel 10th Gen Core i7 stuck at 0.79Ghz and I applied a fix that works, but I don’t understand why this needs to be done?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7

4 months ago I sent my ASUS ROG Strix to ASUS for repair.
The main reason was the CPU running at 0.79Ghz.

Since then I have gotten my laptop back and it worked fine, it also worked fine with Windows 11 for the past 4 months.

Today I  noticed extreme lag. I checked the performance tab in Task Manager and the CPU was stuck at 0.79Ghz.

I then said to myself “It must be the software.”

So I did a clean install of Windows 11 and the problem persisted.

Then I made a clean install of Windows10 and the same problem; CPU stuck at 0.79Ghz.

Then I was fed up and I reinstalled clean Windows 11 and *still* had the problem.

I contacted ASUS and they just told me to send it in for repair.

But then I checked on Google a bit with the only 700Mhz I had.

I found out some Intel CPUs get throttled down to that speed for a reason I can’t even imagine.

So what I found is an application called [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/). I’ve uncheck a box with the option called `BD PROCHOT`. I have no clue what this option is but now my CPU is back up running as it should, 2.6Ghz at normal and 4.2Ghz at turbo.

Is anyone aware of this issue?

I’m not new to PCs but I don’t even know what that checkbox changed in the software for my CPU to start running as it should be.

The fact that I needed software fix for a new CPU is mind boggling. I document all I do such as troubleshooting and all. I feel that ASUS must replace the CPU with its defects.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that one of your system thermal sensors is triggering a thermal overload protection in your CPU.

From the [Intel CPU Datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/products/calpella/core-mobile-datasheet-vol-1.html)

> #### 5.2.1.3.1 Bi-Directional PROCHOT#
>
> By default, the PROCHOT# signal is defined as an output only. However, the signal may be configured as bi-directional. When configured as a bi-directional signal, PROCHOT# can be used for thermally protecting other platform components should they overheat as well.

By default **PROCHOT#** is a signal that the CPU tells the system that it is thermally throttling due to overheating. Your system firmware can choose to reconfigure that signal to be bi-directional and essentially change it to **BD PROCHOT#**.

When in this mode thermal sensors in your chipset or other devices can be used to signal the CPU that the system is experiencing abnormal temperatures and should throttle as a result. What it doesn't do is tell the CPU *where* the problem lies, it is entirely an all or nothing "**something**, ***somewhere*** is wrong." type signal.

By disabling **BD PROCHOT#** using ThrottleStop you are switching back to the "old" style where the CPU controls itself and nothing else matters. The CPU will ignore thermal warnings from the wider system and only throttle when it is overheating itself.

I would recommend using a program such as [hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to look at all the sensors available in your system to see if there are any that are showing high temperatures.

Comment: By touch on the laptop chassis i feel no overheating as usual.
Things heat up a bit while gaming but its normal.
The temperatures seem fine to my knowlage (Using pcs since 1994).
May it be a defect in the cpu sensor ?

Comment: It may well be a problem with the system firmware getting confused and sending a signal when it shouldn't. "By touch" tells you nothing about the actual sensors in other chips around your system but I've seen this kind of thing being reported a lot over the last few years and it does sound like there's something that may be going wrong. If unchecking BD PROCHOT fixes your problem then it is the wider system and not your CPU that is at fault.

Comment: i feel like this could be a class action to be honest.

Comment: @AverageDude - It’s not

Comment: @AverageDude Against who? This isn't a CPU bug, nor is it a chipset bug, and it is more down to board design, cooling and general handling of the system. You could have a piece of lint collected around a chip with a thermal diode in it that is now reporting slightly higher temperatures while the rest of the system is cool. Or you could have something running and causing the hard drive controller to report a high temperature. Without investigation it is hard to know what your actual problem is which why your manufacturer want to look at it. "Class action" is bandied around far too lightly.

Comment: @AverageDude: “I feel like this could be a class action to be honest.” Do you want your PC fixed or do you want to threaten empty legal action? The reality is the CPU is not at fault but the ASUS board design is at fault. How do you propose that class action suit would happen? That would mean you would need to get a legal team to act on this and maybe in years you will get, like, a $50 check to be honest. If you are upset, honestly return the PC to ASUS for a full refund and buy another brand. Nothing else is practical. This solution of the `BD PROCHOT` setting is sadly valid and useful.