# 0.39 ghz laptop CPU

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance, 64-bit, x86

Almost everytime I open my laptop and it wakes from sleep, the cpu clock is stuck at 0.39 ghz and I always have to wait for around 30 seconds for it to return to normal. I have a very good Asus laptop with an nvme ssd and an i7 10th gen cpu. The model is `ASUS UX425JA`. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Does it simply take 30 seconds to reach normal operating temperature?

Comment: Yes, around 30 seconds to reach normal cpu clock speed

Comment: Yes, you won't have normal speed until the CPU has warmed up - which takes 30 seconds.

Comment: It is probably the time required for the chipset to go through all the system thermal sensors and release any throttling. It's likely to protect against turning back on after overheat events.

Comment: A CPU warming up? Come on, a CPU would overheat instantly (within a few seconds) without any cooling, whatever is happening has nothing to do with the CPU “warming up”.

Comment: CPU warming up is a bit of a reach, but the chipset checking thermal sensors and making sure that the fan is running and working properly before releasing [BD PROCHOT](https://superuser.com/a/1686163/19943) is vaguely plausible. It's a bit of a long time though, so it might be worth checking if your system has any firmware updates for the motherboard.

Comment: Sounds to be like the CPU is being throttled for running too hot, have you checked for good ventilation?

Comment: @Mokubai - The thermal sensors used to measure the temperature of a CPU don’t need time to warm up, they themselves are digital, which measure a probe. If anything the CPU is being throttled and that is taking 30 seconds to cool (although that’s a LONG time to cool a cpu)

Comment: @Ramhound but the problem is not necessarily in the CPU and I'm not talking about the time to warm up, I'm talking about the time to scan around an I2C or SPI bus looking for all the various *other* sensors and get what you think are sensible readings for them in order for the chipset to release their control of the CPU thermal throttling. If you look at the "BD PROCHOT" answer I posted you can see that the chipset can be given control of when the CPU is throttling based on whether it thinks other sensors are abnormal. The result is something outside of the OS and CPU deciding to throttle.

Comment: Heck, it could even be that a sensor that is not populated but the system firmware is scanning for and eventually timing out on after 30 seconds at which point it goes "oh, it must be fine because it's not there then". It's stupid, but it's all too easy a mistake to program in if you are being defensive and working on a "everything is bad until we know it's not" standpoint.

Comment: I found the solution here: [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1617971/infamous-0-39-ghz-in-windows-10-issue-has-no-fixes)
The problem was the ACPI setting.

Comment: @YoyoPro glad you found a solution that works for you