# What could cause my OS to be slow?

Tags: linux, windows, performance, malware

My dual boot linux-windows got slow on both operating systems. The GUI components render slow and sluggish.

I've tried everything I know but haven't been able to pinpoint the issue.

- Malware: I ran kaspersky rescue disk, ClamAV in Linux, rootkit scanner, Malwarebytes in Windows, they all find nothing.
- Disk: I checked OS SSD performance with crystaldiskinfo/mark, all good
- GPU: monitoring doesn't show anything extraordinary, Furmark stress test went fine, temperatures are normal.

My system is a laptop, i7 with an Intel HD GPU and NVidia 740m GPU.

The slow GUI rendering for everything is maddening to me and I don't know how to troubleshoot this further. Any suggestions?

[image: sensors]

Edit: on inspecting the picture closer, I noticed 'CPU performance limitation reasons'. The reason given is `frequency clipped due to external prochot assertion`.

So the CPU ís getting too hot but it doesn't stand out because it get's clipped. So why is it getting too hot?

I cleaned the air vent not long ago. Maybe thermal paste needs replacement?

Comment: Have you checked your CPU fans and temperatures - possible thermal throttling?

Comment: @DavidPostill CPU temps are ok. I added sensor readings for reference.

Comment: Your cores appear locked to 800MHz which can be a fault due to platform (not CPU) thermal throttling. As a test you can disable BD PROCHOT using [ThrottleStop](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-throttlestop/). Otherwise you might need to remove the battery for a while to try and reset your system firmware, or otherwise look for a firmware upgrade which might fix it. https://superuser.com/a/1686163/19943

Comment: Also check your fans operate correctly and are not blocked. Your system firmware might be detecting some kind of fan or thermal failure and throttling your system as a result.

Comment: @Mokubai & DavidPostill, the culprit has been found thanks to your input. I'll roll with that and look where it brings me.

Comment: @progonkpa glad you found a solution

Answer (score 4):

HWinfo showed the CPUs were locked at 800MHz as pointed out by  @DavidPostill and with the advice of @Mokubai on how to deal with PROCHOT (processor hot) issues, in my case, I had to pull the battery from the laptop and the power cable to reset the firmware. I think this resolved it.

Before that, I also did an upgrade of the [Intel HD graphics driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/75128/intel-core-i74800mq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-70-ghz/downloads.html).

Oddly, HWinfo still notifies throttling but the core MHz are at 3300 and everything flies again. So happy this got resolved. Thanks guys.